# Table per Hierarchy (TPH) Discriminator Value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

We're using the fluent API to map a domain model to an existing database.

The database has a column called Discriminator, but the value stored in the column **is not** the same as the Type that the row relates to.

Given:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int Doors { get; set; }
}

public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public bool Stubby { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this **works:**

```
public class VehicleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Map<Car>(x => x.Requires("Discriminato").HasValue("C"));
        Map<Bike>(x => x.Requires("Discriminato").HasValue("B"));
    }
}
```

and this **does not** (just the requires bit has changed)

```
public class VehicleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Vehicle>
{
    public VehicleMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Map<Car>(x => x.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("C"));
        Map<Bike>(x => x.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("B"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, to clarify what I'm asking:

Why is it not possible to use the default column name, but change the value/type that's stored in that column?

Is it possible?
Is there a workaround if not? (other than changing our schema)

Comment: When you say `doesn't work`, what do you mean? What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework TPH by default uses a column called `Discriminator` and your second code block is messing with that column. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx):

> By default, the discriminator column is added to the table with the
>   name “Discriminator” and the CLR type name of each type in the
>   hierarchy is used for the discriminator values. You can modify the
>   default behavior by using the fluent API.

So if you need to modify it, you need to choose your own name for the column which is what your first code block is doing and calling it `Discriminato`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, I was wanting to modify the default value stored in the column, without actually changing the column name.

Comment: Not sure that is possible. What happens when you try using your code above?

Comment: I get the following exception: 
(11,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 11, 17:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to the same group of rows.

(11,10) : error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 6, 11:EntityTypes ConsoleApplication1.Bike, ConsoleApplication1.Vehicle, ConsoleApplication1.Car are being mapped to the same rows in table Vehicle. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.